# Why is my partial view not updating when I post data in my .Net razor page?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I am building a web application to take orders for a printing business. After an order item is added to the cart, I want the contents of the cart to be updated in a partial view on the same page. The project is a .NET 8.0 Razor application.

PageModel:

```
    [BindProperty]
    public Order Order { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public IFormFile Upload { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public ItemType ItemType { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public string ArtistName { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public decimal HeightInInches { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public decimal WidthInInches { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    
    public CustomerOrderModel(TabunkaPrinting.Data.TabunkaPrintingContext context, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment env, IFileShareHelper fileShareHelper)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.env = env;
        this.fileShareHelper = fileShareHelper;
        Order = new Order();
    }
    
    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        return Page();
    }
    
    public PartialViewResult OnPostOrderItem()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Order.Id))
        {
            Order.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }
    
        var filePath = Path.Combine(this.env.ContentRootPath, "uploads", Upload.FileName);
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            Upload.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
        }
    
        int heightInPx;
        int widthInPx;
        using (Image image = Image.FromFile(filePath)) 
        {
            heightInPx = image.Height;
            widthInPx = image.Width;
        }
            
        string artistName = ArtistName;
        decimal heightInInches = HeightInInches;
        decimal widthInInches = WidthInInches;
        ItemType itemType = ItemType;
        int quantity = Quantity;
    
        Artwork artwork = new Artwork(filePath, artistName, heightInPx, widthInPx);
    
        OrderItem orderItem = new OrderItem()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            OrderId = Order.Id,
            Artwork = artwork,
            HeightInInches = heightInInches,
            WidthInInches = widthInInches,
            ItemType = itemType,
            Quantity = quantity,
            TotalPriceInDollars = (heightInInches * widthInInches) * PricePerSquareInch
        };
    
        Order.AddOrderItem(orderItem);
    
        return Partial("_OrderItemsPartial", Order.OrderItems);
    }
```

Order Page:

```
@page
@using TabunkaPrinting.Models;
@using System.IO;
@model TabunkaPrinting.Pages.Orders.CustomerOrderModel
@{

    ViewData["Title"] = "Customer Order";
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="row">
    <table>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Upload File
                </th>
                <th>
                    Artist Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Height (Inches)
                </th>
                <th>
                    Width (Inches)
                </th>
                <th>
                    Item Type
                </th>
                <th>
                    Quantity
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <form asp-page-handler="orderitem" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="orderItemForm">
                    <td>
                        <input type="file" asp-for="Upload" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="artistName" type="text" asp-for="ArtistName"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="heightInInches" type="number" asp-for="HeightInInches"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="widthInInches" type="number" asp-for="WidthInInches"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="itemType" asp-for="ItemType" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<ItemType>()"></select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="quantity" type="number" asp-for="Quantity"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button id="addOrderItem" class="btn">
                            Add Item
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </form>
            </tr>
            <partial name="_OrderItemsPartial" model="Model.Order.OrderItems" id="orderItems"></partial>
    </table>
    <div class="col-12">
        <form asp-page-handler="order" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Order.CustomerEmail" class="cointrol-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Order.CustomerEmail" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Order.CustomerEmail" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Order.RecipientName" class="cointrol-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Order.RecipientName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Order.RecipientName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Order.StreetAddress" class="cointrol-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Order.StreetAddress" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Order.StreetAddress" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Order.City" class="cointrol-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Order.City" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Order.City" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Order.State" class="cointrol-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Order.State" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Order.State" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Order.ZipCode" class="cointrol-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Order.ZipCode" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Order.ZipCode" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@section scripts{
    <script>
        document.getElementById('addOrderItem').addEventListener("click", function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/CustomerOrder?handler=OrderItem',
                method: "POST",
                data: $('#orderItemForm').serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#orderItems").html(result);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Partial View (located at Pages\Shared\_OrderItemsPartial.cshtml):

```
@using Printing.Models

@model List<OrderItem>

@foreach (var orderItem in Model)
{
    string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(orderItem.Artwork.FilePath);
    string itemType = orderItem.ItemType.ToString();
    string quantity = orderItem.Quantity.ToString();
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(item => fileName);
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(item => orderItem.Artwork.Artist);
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(item => orderItem.HeightInInches);
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(item => orderItem.WidthInInches);
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(item => itemType);
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(item => quantity);
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

The post seems to work fine, as the image file is successfully uploaded and data is saved. However, when the partial view is returned, I get **only** the partial view, rather than the partial view within my 'primary' view. Html that is returned looks like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        imageName.png;
    </td>
    <td>
        artistName;
    </td>
    <td>
        5.00;
    </td>
    <td>
        5.00;
    </td>
    <td>
        Gloss;
    </td>
    <td>
        1;
    </td>
</tr>
```

Rather than **only** the partial view being returned, I need the <partial> tag in my primary view to be replaced with the partial view. What am I doing wrong? I have been trying to closely follow learnrazorpages.com, but have had no luck in solving this problem.

Comment: I can see the location  `Pages\Shared_OrderItemsPartial.cshtml` is wrong. If this is NOT a typo, fix it to be  `Pages\Shared\_OrderItemsPartial.cshtml`

Comment: Also consider using `@Html.RenderPartial` or `IHtmlHelper.PartialAsync` instead of the partial tag helper as the use of `IHtmlHelper.Partial` may result in application deadlocks.

Comment: If you do not specify `type="button"` inside the button, it will submit the form by default. Add `type="button"` to `<button id="addOrderItem"></button>` to avoid automatically form submission.

Comment: @ecemy, thank you for pointing out the typo. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

> The post seems to work fine, as the image file is successfully
> uploaded and data is saved. However, when the partial view is
> returned, I get only the partial view, rather than the partial view
> within my 'primary' view.

That is because you do not specify `type="button"` inside the button, otherwise it will submit the form by default.

Change your button to:

```
<button id="addOrderItem" class="btn" type="button">
     Add Item
</button>
```

Another way, you can prevent the default action of the submit button's click event by using `event.preventDefault();` without change the `button`:

```
document.getElementById('addOrderItem').addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    // Prevent the default form submission behavior
    event.preventDefault();

    // Perform your AJAX request
        
});
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your help.

So I have two forms on this page. The first form is for adding an order item to the cart. The second form is for submitting the cart with the customer info (email, etc). 

I want the first form to be submitted so that the image is uploaded to the server and order item info is saved. After the request is posted, I want the partial view returned with the cart information. I followed your guidance and it results in the first form not being submitted, which is what I want.